# Docker for Windows "The system cannot find the path specified" when trying to install Shopware 6 locally

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows, shopware

I'm using Docker for Windows and I am trying to install Shopware 6 with the dockware image.

When I enter command:
`docker cp shopware:/var/www/html/. ./src`
it copies some files, but after some waiting time I get the following error:
`C:\mypath\src\vendor\shopware\administration\Resources\app\administration\node_modules\.cache\terser-webpack-plugin\content-v2\sha512\69\3c\9b1ea7d80f60c821b53797c0afe66e6b56c9637c96d7e70bbd16d7911ef6cd73eae0ac183fa8811f363a3c04742ad3efd1254748e650129d83c4b10522cb:`  The system cannot find the path specified

I also tried to install it on a different Windows-PC - same error.

- Docker for Windows v 3.2.2
- dockware/dev:6.3.5.1

I'm following these installation instructions: https://docs.dockware.io/development/start-developing

What I tried so far

- using Windows cmd/Powershell/VSCode terminal
- starting terminal(s) as administrator
- using Docker for Windows v 2.5.0.0
- using dockware/dev:6.3.2
- Enable NTFS long paths (registry entry HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem)

It worked a few months ago, I don't know whats different this time...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The error your are seeing is related to the webpack cache. Webpack is used to build the frontend code for shopware.

If the webpack processes are running, this cache can change often.

I would say this error is quite random and it's safe to ignore this error and try it again. What happens if you do you? Do you get an error on the same path or on a new one?

Comment: With me it happens all the time when I run this comment. What can i do?

Comment: I think ignoring it doesn't help, as I see not all the directories are copied. For instance there is no "StoreFront" directory. I have the same problem as Phil.